# Why can't call all __init__ when super() with Multiple Inheritance?

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Show the code:

```
class state():
    def __init__(self):
        print('in the state class')
        self.state = "main state"

class event():
    def __init__(self):
        print("in the event class")
        self.event = "main event"

class happystate(state,event):
    def __init__(self):
        print('in the happy state class')
        super(state,self).__init__()
        super(event,self).__init__()
```

`happystate` has two base class--`state` and `event`,initialize the `happystate`.

```
a = happystate()
in the happy state class
in the event class
```

Why can't call state class?

Comment: That's not how ``super`` works. ``super(state,self).__init__`` does not mean "``__init__`` on the super class *which is ``state``*", it means "``__init__`` on the super class *which is in ``self``'s mro after ``state``*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use `super().__init__()` in other classes, and you have multiple inheritance, python stops running other `__init__` methods.

```py
class state():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('in the state class')
        self.state = "main state"

class event():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("in the event class")
        self.event = "main event"

class happystate(state,event):
    def __init__(self):
        print('in the happy state class')
        super().__init__()
```

I am adding some references:

1. [From Raymond Hettinger](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)
2. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Answer (score -1):

As MisterMiyagi say that super(state,self).**init** does not mean "**init** on the super class which is state", it means "**init** on the super class which is in self's mro after state".

We can remove all the `super().__init__()` in class `state` and `event` with such other way as below:

```
class state():
    def __init__(self):
        print('in the state class')
        self.state = "main state"

class event():
    def __init__(self):
        print("in the event class")
        self.event = "main event"

class happystate(state,event):
    def __init__(self):
        print('in the happy state class')
        super(happystate,self).__init__()
        super(state,self).__init__()
```

Initialize the class `happystate`:

```
>>> x = happystate()
in the happy state class
in the state class
in the event class
>>> x.state
'main state'
>>> x.event
'main event'
```

Comment: This is really bad. You should never do this. Read the article from Raymond. Issue with this solution is, that you cannot more extend your code. For example if your code become more complex and `state` or `event` will have to inherit from some king of  `base` class, it won't be working anymore.